# How to wrap some text in vim with '', "", (), [], {}, etc?

Tags: vim

I'm new to vim. And I'm pressing too many buttons doing basic text wrapping:

1. `string` -> `"string"`
2. `long string with many words` -> `'long string with many words'`
3. `a + b * c` -> `(a + b) * c`
4. `(elem0, elem1, elem2)` -> `[elem0, elem1, elem2]` *(optional)*

I'm doing all that manually: go to begin, Insert mode, press key, Normal mode, (the same for second character).

How to do it *faster*? E.g.: visually select the text, smart-wrap it with what you need. Or even without visual selection.

Comment: [surround.vim plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Amadan, thank you. I'm trying not to install plugins while I'm learning basics (I have just 2 plugins installed right now). But it looks like a must have plugin!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `string` -> `"string"`

   ```
   ciw"<C-r>""
   ```
2. `long string with many words` -> `'long string with many words'`

   ```
   veeeeec'<C-r>"'
   ```
3. `a + b * c` -> `(a + b) * c`

   ```
   vwwc(<C-r>")
   ```
4. `(elem0, elem1, elem2)` -> `[elem0, elem1, elem2]` (optional)

   ```
   "edibxs[<C-r>e]
   ```

   That one is a bit more complicated:

   ```
   "edib        cut the content of those parentheses into
                an arbitrary register, here I used "e

   xs           cut the closing parenthese then cut the opening one
                and enter insert mode

   [<C-r>e]     insert the opening bracket, followed by the content of
                register e, followed by the closing bracket
   ```

But yeah, use Tim Pope's Surround.

Comment: FWIW, I revisited the idea recently [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/ca742f241457b8609836202fe05ee5c0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use visuall mode for this. For example you have `string`. `^` will be cursor positioning. Start in normal mode

```
1. string # press viwc(your word will be selected and deleted to unnamed register)
   ^
2. # press " and then <C-r>"(this will paste your selected text) and then press again "
```

This method can be with any surrounding parenthesis or brackets and with any number of words. you just need to change your selection in visual mode